# JAX's slow performance on simple loops

Tags: loops, jax

I'm learning JAX and trying to do a simple test on the performance of JAX. The run time of the following code using JAX is weirdly slower than numpy or even simple addition of list members using python lists. I mean the following code has no purpose other than testing the speed.

I'm wondering what might be the reason for this? I see that there is a functionality of JAX called "fori_loop" that may help in this examples or I can vectorize my actual code, but I want to know why this simple loop is so slow and do I need to avoid writing code like this and completely understand things in the JAX way?

Here is the code in JAX:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random
import time

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
x = random.uniform(key, shape=(100,3))

def func(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            x[i]+x[j]
    return 0

a = time.time()
res = func(x)
b = time.time()
print(b-a)
```

which takes 11 seconds

```py
No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and rerun for more info.)
11.254772663116455
```

The same code using Numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.random.rand(100,3)

def func(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            x[i]+x[j]
    return 0

a = time.time()
res = func(x)
b = time.time()
print(b-a)
```

takes around a milli second:

```py
0.005955934524536133
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in comparing the speed of JAX vs. NumPy speed, the place to start is here: [JAX FAQ: Is JAX Faster Than NumPy?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-jax-faster-than-numpy) Quoting from there:

> in summary: if you’re doing microbenchmarks of individual array operations on CPU, you can generally expect NumPy to outperform JAX due to its lower per-operation dispatch overhead. If you’re running your code on GPU or TPU, or are benchmarking more complicated JIT-compiled sequences of operations on CPU, you can generally expect JAX to outperform NumPy.

Your benchmark does many individual array operations, each of which is very inexpensive, so effectively all you're measuring is the single-operation dispatch time. This is precisely in the regime where we'd expect NumPy to be fast, and JAX to be slow.

For real use-cases involving repeated operations, there are several ways you might optimize the code (including wrapping the whole function in `jit`, using `vmap` for efficient batching, or using `fori_loop` for sequential operations) but for the example function you give it's hard to say what's best. Taking your example at face value, I'd optimize it this way:

```py
def func(x):
  return 0
```

As written, there's no need to do any operations on `x` at all (but I suspect that's not particularly helpful for your real use-case).